# Probability that the Maximum of Many Normal Draws from Multiple Classes is of one Class

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, extreme-value

Given a set of $N=n_i+n_j+n_k$ draws from distributions $N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2), N(\mu_j,\sigma_j^2), N(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2)$, what is the probability that the maximum drawn value was from distribution $i,j,$ or $k$?

Comment: There's no simple answer: you just have to do the (painful) calculation numerically--and that assumes the draws were independent. Possibly you could make some progress if there are specific relationships among the parameters; for instance, you might be able to obtain good asymptotic results as the $n_i$ grow large.